# Heroku error Installing node modules because core-js not accessible

Tags: node.js, heroku, nestjs

Heroku error:

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! core-js not accessible from babel-runtime
```

Where is core-js module?
Where is babel-runtime config or what?

Config vars set as: NODE_ENV=production and NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

package.json

```
    {
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc --sourceMap false",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: $ node --version
v14.17.4
$ nest --version
8.1.0
$ npm --version
6.14.14

Comment: tsconfig.json: ` { "compilerOptions": { "module": "commonjs", "declaration": true, "removeComments": true, "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, "experimentalDecorators": true, "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, "target": "es6", "sourceMap": true, "outDir": "./dist", "baseUrl": "./", "incremental": true, "skipLibCheck": true } }